# How to ensure application integrity on SharePoint 2010

Tags: development

I'm a SharePoint development beginner and I would like to develop a custom application on top of SharePoint Foundation 2010. I decided to write few visual web parts for simple logic and Silverlight web parts for complex application logic.

My application will use its own data in a separate DB. The only connection between my DB and SharePoint DB will be users. Users will authenticate against SharePoint and access my application from there.

Within my application (and DB), all these users will be hierarchically related (*I don't know if this is easily possible in Active Directory so that I could avoid one part of user administration?*) and they will also define certain rights within my application.

**Problem?**

If I do write web parts (of whatever kind), how do I ensure that these same web parts are not used in other SharePoint sites as well? It would probably break the application and it could, of course, make it possible to replicate the same application but using different users.

I thought of writing application pages (my application would be in _layouts folder as I understand it), which would make it possible to *not* reuse my application, but users and rights are assigned on site level... So I can't win this way either.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint does not provide authentication. User accounts in SharePoint are authenticated by Active Directory or ASP.Net Membership providers.

Why are you using SharePoint for the application if you will not be using any of the SharePoint functionality?

Perhaps you should simply write the application in ASP.Net and use the Page Viewer Web Part to display your application on a SharePoint web part page.

Comment: Users will authenticate against Sharepoint. They will be authorised based on settings in Sharepoint. I'm developing an app on Sharepoint because the clients wants it to be integrated with Sharepoint. So users won't authenticate twice and for very strict security measures (client certificates) I won't have to deal with authentication whatsoever.

Comment: Page viewer web part is not an option since it uses IFRAME which means that users authenticated in Sharepoint won't be authenticated in my application. I won't have any security info from SP. I will use user data from Sharepoint.

Comment: An IFrame doesn't negate authentication, they just need to be able to authenticate to both systems.  If both are setup properly with Windows Auth, a domain user will not be prompted for either site.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at Robin Meure's [Feature Blocker](http://community.zevenseas.com/Blogs/Robin/archive/2010/01/29/updated-featureblocker.aspx). I am not sure if it has been updated for SharePoint 2010 though.

There are a number of alternative approaches you can take. For full control you may want to check the URL of the Site Collection the Web part is running on and see if it matches a list of 'allowed sites'.